# Can't get my MVC extended HtmlHelper class to work properly (error: Try specifying the type arguments explicitly)

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I am quite new to MVC but have worked with .NET since 1.1. I have this very confusing issue, where I don't understand what I am doing wrong. It has to do with creating my own HtmlHelper class.

- I am running MVC 5.1
- Razor
- I've checked that web.config looks correct by creating a test project
- I've recreated the issue in a completely new project, to make sure nothing was wrong in the one I've been working on

I am using the following guide: http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/inline-razor-helper-instead-of-html-helper-for-you-asp-net-mvc-website

I've basically done it row by row.

This is from my test project. This is my helper class in the App_Code folder.

```
namespace Test2.MyHtmlHelper
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString TestEditorFor(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string expression)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString("test");
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString TestHelperFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString("test2");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my cshtml:

```
@model Test2.Area
@using Test2.MyHtmlHelper

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                @Html.TestEditorFor("test") @*--works*@
                @Html.TestEditorFor(model => model.Name) @*--error*@
                @Html.TestHelperFor(b => b.name) @*--error*@

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

So two issues. The first one is with the following line of code:

@Html.TestHelperFor(b => b.name)

```
The type arguments for method 'Test2.MyHtmlHelper.HtmlExtensions.YourGenericHelperFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

I thought that reflection was supposed to automagically find out this, so you don't have to type arguments explicitely. It even says so in the guide: "As you can see, the Html Helper does not know about how the model class is made from. It just knowns that it takes by parameter an expression where we will get by reflection the property and its value."

The second issue is that as soon as I use a lambda expression referencing the model with my helper methods, there is no reference. With @Html.TestEditorFor(model => model.Name), when I check the intellisense on model it says "(parameter) ? model". But with @Html.EditorFor it says "Area model", which is correct. I guess it has to do with my method not knowing what to accept, but once again, should it not be dealt with automatically?

Feel like a noob but already spent an afternoon trying to solve this and I about to give up for now, and just work around it.

Comment: seems that your link down (Page not found)"I am using the following guide:"

Comment: Thanks. Link updated to correct one: http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/inline-razor-helper-instead-of-html-helper-for-you-asp-net-mvc-website

Answer (score 3):

this works for me

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString TestEditorFor(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string expression)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString("test");
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString TestHelperFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString("test2");
    }
}



 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.TestEditorFor("test") 
        @Html.TestHelperFor(model => model.name) 
        @Html.TestHelperFor(b => b.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.TestEditorFor(model => model.Name) @*--error*@
```

is expecting a string value, not an expression

```
@Html.TestHelperFor(b => b.name) @*--error*@
```

shouldn't this be b.Name instead of b.name?